# Mongoose - Multi-level navigation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new to MongoDB & Mongoose

I have data like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327417",
  "title": "Hahaha",
  "parent": null,
  "depth": 0
},
{
  "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327416",
  "title": "Hihihi",
  "parent": null,
  "depth": 0
},
{
  "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327415",
  "title": "Huhuhu",
  "parent": "5787009e494495e56d327417",
  "depth": 1
}
```

How can I convert the data into this:

```
{
  "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327417",
  "title": "Hahaha",
  "children": [
     "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327415",
     "title": "Huhuhu",
     "children": []
  ]
},
{
  "_id": "5787009e494495e56d327416",
  "title": "Hihihi",
  "children": []
}
```

Please help me, and sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way you have to traverse the result and create new Data in memory.

```
//for each item in the result {
     if(item.parent !=null){
       insert_item_in_tree(item);   
     }
//}
```

then build a data structure function to insert the one item appropriately as per parent id.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Should i use the option with `parent` objectId or the option with `children` array for the data ?

Comment: parent is better because storing is less. and modification is easy.

Comment: however the tree that you build in memory can be designed the way your use case demand. How you want to traverse etc.    don't forget to accept the answer if you liked it.